# Fire change-event manually

Tags: javascript, events, jsf, primefaces, onchange

Hey I've got a problem with fireing a change-event manually.

So I have a selectOneMenu (i'ts like a dropdown in jsf) with different values.

If I choose a value of this dropdown-list, a datatable should be updated. This works correctly, if i choose this value manually.

Now there is a case, where I need to insert a new value to the selectOneMenu. This new value gets selected automatically, but the change-event to update the datatable doesn't get fired...

So basically I have this button to save a new value to the selectOneMenu which then gets selected correctly, but the datatable doesn't get updated, which is why I tried to write the function fireChange() and gave that to the oncomplete of the button:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="true" id="seatingPlanSave" actionListener="#{EventAssistentController.createSeatingPlan}" value="#{msg.save}" update=":createEvent:EventSeatingPlan, :createEvent:ticketTypePrices" oncomplete="fireChange()"/>
```

For the fireChange()-function, i tried a few different things:

```
function fireChange() {
    var element = document.getElementById("createEvent:EventSeatingPlan_input");
    element.change();
}


function fireChange() {
    var element = document.getElementById("createEvent:EventSeatingPlan_input");
    $(element).trigger("change");
}


function fireChange() {
    if ("fireEvent" in element)
        element.fireEvent("onchange");
    else {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

But none of these work :(

Can you please tell me how I can achieve this?

Thanks, Xera

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't tell anything about the HTML representation of `createEvent:EventSeatingPlan_input` while that's mandatory for us (and you!) in order to know how to let JS intercept on that. You didn't tell either if you were using `<h:selectOneMenu>` or `<p:selectOneMenu>`, so we can't take a look ourselves in the generated HTML representation. The former generates a `<select><option>` while the latter generates an `<div><ul><li>` which interacts with a hidden `<select><option>`. Both representations of dropdown menus require a different approach in JS. Also, information about how you're registering the `change` event handler function is mandatory. Is it by hardocing the `onchange` attribute, or by embedding a `<f:ajax>` or `<p:ajax>`?

In any way, based on the information provided so far, I'll *guess* that you've a

```html
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
    <f:ajax render="dataTableId" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

which will generate a `<select onchange="..."><option>`.

As per your first attempt:

```
function fireChange() {
    var element = document.getElementById("createEvent:EventSeatingPlan_input");
    element.change();
}
```

This will fail on `<h:selectOneMenu>` because [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) interface doesn't have a `change` property nor method. Instead, it is `onchange` property which returns a event handler which can directly be invoked by appending `()`.

The following will work on `<h:selectOneMenu>`:

```
function fireChange() {
    var element = document.getElementById("createEvent:EventSeatingPlan_input");
    element.onchange();
}
```

However this will in turn fail in `<p:selectOneMenu>`, because it returns a `HTMLDivElement` instead of `HtmlSelectElement`. The `HTMLDivElement` doesn't have a `onchange` property which returns an event handler. As said, the `<p:selectOneMenu>` generates a `<div><ul><li>` widget which interacts with a hidden `<select><option>`. You should be registering this widget in JS context and then use its special `triggerChange()` method.

So, given a

```
<p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="w_menu" ...>
    <p:ajax update="dateTableId" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

this should do

```
function fireChange() {
    w_menu.triggerChange();
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much for this great answer!

I use a <p:selectOneMenu> and as you suggested with the widgetVar and the special triggerChange-Method it works perfectly now :-)

Thanks again and have a nice day